# Magento 2: CLI command is taking too much time to execute

Tags: magento2, cli

I have installed the docker and my Magento project deployed on docker, the issue is CLI command is taking too much time to execute.[image]

Comment: In case you have xdebug enabled, you can try disabling it to see if something changes

Answer (score 0):

Try to run

```
bin/magento cache:enable
```

Also, check mount options. As I can see, you use Ubuntu at least 18.04 version. That means that you can try to use nfs4, tcp, no-lock and so on in folders mount options.
Sorry, I'm not an expert in docker but had the same issue with vagrant and enabling caches, configuring mounting options and rebooting the machine helped me.